# Hiding output with 0 query value with php

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help with this? I have a query that displays a value on the website but I would like to hide the output if it is 0 (zero). There are 2 fields, one called COI and the other AVK. They display as a percent such as COI: 12.00% AVK: 34.56%.

If the value is 0 then they display as COI: 0.00% and/or AVK 0.00%. I would like to not show this at all.

The code is specific and I can't find examples that would apply to this situation. Thought maybe an an else if but I just can't quite figure it out.

Appreciate any help!

UPDATE: Found a solution & have edited the code to show what was added. Hopefully this will help someone else if they have a similar issue.

```
        echo "<span class='subjectdetails'>";
    $nIndex = 11;
    $nMarkIndex = -1;
    foreach ($aExtraFields as $extraField)
    {
        $extraField = trim($extraField);
        $subField = trim($details[$nIndex]);
        if (($extraField == 'COI') and ($subField > 0)) <----- added this
            $subField = sprintf("%.2f%%", $subField * 100);
        if (($extraField == 'AVK') and ($subField > 0))  <----- added this
            $subField = sprintf("%.2f%%", $subField * 100);         
        if (!empty($subField) && $extraField[0] != '_')// Don't print extra fields if they begin with underscore
        if ((!empty($subField) && $extraField[0] != 'C')  ||  $extraField == 'COI')
        if ((!empty($subField) && $extraField[0] != 'A')  ||  $extraField == 'AVK')
         if (!empty($subField) && $extraField[0] != 'M')// Don't print extra fields if they begin with M                    
            echo "$extraField: $subField<br/>" ;
        if ($extraField == '_Marks')
            $nMarkIndex = $nIndex;
        $nIndex++;
    }
```

Comment: `!empty()` is inappropriate when the variable guaranteed to exist.

Comment: It's used here as there are fields that don't need to show in that section of the page... and are not always empty. For example, I have another field that starts with C but I only want COI to appear, not Created. Same with A, only AVK not AKCCorrections or AddedBy. Is there perhaps a better way?

Comment: `empty()` makes two checks when executed.  1. If the variable is not declared and 2. If the value of that variable is falsey/null/zeroish.  You only need the latter of the two.  No function call is necessary for a truthy check. Also, why not `in_array($extraField, ['COI', 'AVK'])` ?  All `condition blocks should use curly braces for clarity.  See PSR standards.

Comment: Your code, IMO, needs to be completely refactored.  However, we cannot fully understand your needs without a [mcve]. We need to see `$aExtraFields` and `$details` with just enough data to represent your logical challenge.  I don't understand why you start at eleven and unconditionally increment that number in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can just check `$subfield` with another `if`. If it's 0 then set `$subfield` to '';

```php
if ($extraField == 'COI') {
   if($subField) {
       $subField = sprintf("%.2f%%", $subField * 100);
   } else {
       $subField = '';
   }
   
}
```

Comment: I tried that but ended up with a blank area with no data displayed. I don't think it's that simple due to the echo statement. Maybe I have the syntax wrong?